# TypeError: function missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I copy this (down below) code from the Tech with Tim Youtube Channel, but it doesnt work, and give me the next error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bence/Python/Game/kakaó.py", line 86, in <module>
    redrawGameWindow()
  File "C:/Users/bence/Python/Game/kakaó.py", line 40, in redrawGameWindow
    win.blit(walkright[walkcount//3])
TypeError: function missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2)
```

The code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

clock= pygame.time.Clock()

x= 50
y=450
width=64
height=64
vel=5
left = False
right = False
iJ=False
jC=10
walkcount = 0

pygame.display.set_caption("Karifa Game")

walkright = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'),pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkleft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'),pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

run = True

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkcount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))

    if walkcount + 1 >= 27:
        walkcount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkleft[walkcount//3])
        walkcount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkright[walkcount//3])
        walkcount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x,y))
    pygame.display.update()


while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x> vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x< 500-width-vel:
        x += vel
        left = False
        right = True
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkcount = 0
    if not (iJ):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                 iJ = True
                 right = False
                 left = False
                 walkcount = 0
    else:
        if jC >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jC < 0:
                neg = -1
            y-=(jC**2) *0.5 *neg
            jC -= 1

        else:
            iJ = False
            jC=10

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

If anyone knows the solution please answer, Thanks!

Comment: `blit` takes two inputs like you haev done earlier in your code `win.blit(bg, (0,0))` however later in your code you call blit with only one input `win.blit(walkleft[walkcount//3])` so the code is telling you that your missing a position argument that would tell blit where

Comment: Thanks, I put  the parameters into my code, and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Wait! I found a solution, you simply put in parantheses the x and y value of your character, on both walkLeft and walkRight. This is the so called missing 'dest'. An example below:

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

if walkCount +1 >= 27:
    walkCount = 0

if left:
    win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))
    walkCount += 1

elif right:
    win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x, y))
    walkCount +=1

else:
    win.blit(char, (x, y))

pygame.display.update()
```

It should work now. You may consider resetting x and y starting positions for a more logical game.